# How to select values of a dataset if it fits in ranges of another dataset in python?

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I have 2 genetic datasets. One with rows of ranges of the genome, each assigned a measurement, and another of specific positions on the genome. I am looking to match the second dataset with its rows with a genome position that fall in any of the ranges of the first dataset. They must be inside the range and on the same chromosome.

For example:

```
dataset1:
Chromosome  Start  End   Score
    1       100    200     50
    1       200    250     10
    2       10     20000   40
    2       100    200     20
    3       100    200     10
```

```
dataset2:
Chromosome  Position
    1          150
    2          157
    2          1067
    3           5
```

Matching up dataset2 to the positions that fall in the `Start` and `End` range of dataset1 (and have the same `Chromosome`) and assigning them the scores would give:

```
Chromosome  Position     Score
    1          150         50
    2          157         20
    2          1067        40
    3           5          NA
```

A position on chromosome 2 matches 2 scores so would need to be duplicated to be assigned both scores. I normally code this in R, and don't use Python as much, I have no idea where to start with doing this in Python - are there any functions I should look into using that can do this?

Comment: This row doesn't look valid?
2          157         10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will give all rows of dataset2 where Position is in the range, with one row per condition met:

```
df = dataset2.merge(dataset1, on='Chromosome')
res = df[(df.Position >= df.Start) & (df.Position <= df.End)][['Chromosome', 'Position', 'Score']

print(res)
```

Output:

```
   Chromosome  Position  Score
0           1       150     50
2           2       157     40
3           2       157     20
4           2      1067     40
```